# In an SQL Developer query result window, how do I see the value of an object in a column?

Tags: object, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I run a query in SQL Developer and one of the columns returned is an object is there any way I can see the value of the object without changing the query?
It comes back like this:

DEPTNO DEPTNAME ADDRESS

```
1        SALES       [HR.ADDRESS_T]

2        ST          [HR.ADDRESS_T]

3        APPS        [HR.ADDRESS_T]
```

where address_t is an object.I would like to see the values  of the object address_t, like street city state zip code.

Comment: select * from address_t ;   Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: My query was select * from depts. I want to get the actual values of the object address_t associated with a dept. It shows them in sqlplus. Sometime SQL Developer shows the actual values sometimes the object name, I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: can you please post the structure of both tables, sample data and the expected output?

Comment: If I double-click on the object name (HR.ADDRESS_T above) it will show the object with its values.